# List files greater than a given size in horizontal pixels

Tags: perl, list, imagemagick

I am trying to create a perl script that will list all files in the current directory with a horizontal pixel resolution greater than a given size.

So far I have tried experimenting with ls and identify but have not been able to find a solution.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What the heck is the "horizontal pixel resolution" of a file?

Comment: The width of the image in pixels horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Image::Size](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-Size/lib/Image/Size.pm).

```
use Image::Size;
use constant GIVEN_WIDTH = '100';
my @filtered_images = grep { my @d = imgsize( $_ ); $d[0] > GIVEN_WIDTH } @images;
```